# Communication between two computers using an Internet Browser and Sockets?

Tags: sockets, webserver, websocket

How may I create a socket on my computer that could be reachable from other computers via internet, and work like a web server, maybe using WebSockets?

By the way: could my web server become visible from the Internet and how?

---

*I know I can install a LAMP web server on my computer (my OS is Ubuntu) and use it for a local network.*
*I know I can use sockets to let 2 computers communicate via internet using their IP addresses (I did it in Java).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your LAMP server stack accessible from the internet by forwarding ports from your external internet connection to the computer the server stack is running on. If you're doing this at home, you can usually handle port forwarding from the admin interface for your router/modem.

Alternatively, [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) is a newer web technology (still in the testing phase) that allows two browsers to connect to each other without the need for an intermediate web server.

Comment: Thanks. I would appreciate details about make my LAMP server accessible using Ubuntu and this modem:

Huawei E173

Comment: That doesn't fit in on Stack Overflow. You should first Google for "port forwarding huawei e173", then if you can't figure it out, ask a question on SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

Browser does not permit raw sockets.
You can not create a socket from browser, because it would be security hole.
For example you download a page from internet and script on this page opened all sockets on your computer.

Websockets it is technology on top of TCP protocol.
Using Websockets you can connect two browsers to a Websocket server and exchange information via this server.